# MySQL on ubuntu 12.04 won't run after MySQL Workbench installed

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, mysql-workbench

Recently I installed MySQL Workbench 6.2 and used it to create ER diagrams of the MySQL 5.5.41 databases I'm working with on Ubuntu 12.04.  Everything worked fine until I restarted Ubuntu and suddenly mysql was no longer running.  Running mysqld from the command line results in this:

```
150216 12:50:37 [ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'
150216 12:50:37 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/euler.lower-test
150216 12:50:37 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/euler.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)
150216 12:50:37 [ERROR] Aborting

150216 12:50:37 [Note]
```

The file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys exists, owned by root, with permissions 644.  The directory /var/lib/mysql exists, owned by mysql, with permissions 700.

I'm guessing that the installation of Workbench changed something (maybe config files) so that mysql is no longer working, but after a fair amount of Internet research, I have not discovered how to solve this problem.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like file permission problem. Try running mysqld again using `sudo`

If this doesn't help, maybe you shouldn't be starting it directly via mysqld. Check if the installer package added a service

```
sudo service --status-all | grep mysql
```

And if one exist, use it to start mysql, typically:

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

Also don't forget to check if mysqld is already running. If so you can't start duplicate process. I know this sound silly but has happened to me before

```
ps -ef | grep mysqld
```

Comment: All the error and warning messages went away except the first one:  Can't read from messagefile, but mysqld is still not running.

Comment: mysqld is not shown as a service, nor is it running.  I'm afraid I'm going to have to reinstall mysql.